# Illegal Character Message When Attaching to List Item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When attempting to attach a file to a list item, we get an error message that the file name contains illegal characters. The file(s) in question only have alpha characters in the file name. It seems as though it is detecting the "\" character in the file path. File attachments have worked previously. There are attachments on all the other items in the same container.

I don't have a lot of SharePoint experience and am not quite sure where to even start with this. Trying to find answers in other threads and on other websites has not yielded any results. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've included a screenshot below with an example file and the error message that is received.

[image: SharePoint Error]

Answer (score 0):

I found some further information [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5dc44e6e-b5bd-47f8-a75d-71c9841f9ace/august-2015-cu-list-attachments-give-file-names-cant-contain-the-following-characters-message?forum=sharepointadmin) which led me to [this link](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2015/08/august-2015-cu-error-file-names-cant-contain-the-following-characters/). The workaround of editing the JavaScript files on the SharePoint server is working for the moment. All credit to Trevor from Nauplius:

### Workaround

A temporary workaround is available for this issue, but involves editing files in the 15 hive. Prior to performing this, make backup copies of these files. These backups must be in place prior to installing the next SharePoint patch.

There are two JavaScript files that must be edited:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\FORM.debug.js
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\FORM.JS
```

For `Form.debug.js`, change the text starting on line 5307 from:

```
    else {
    if (IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName(filename) != -1) {
        alert(Strings.STS.L_IllegalFileNameError);
        return;
    }
```

To:

```
    else {
var filNameOnly = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    if (IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName(filNameOnly) != -1) {
        alert(Strings.STS.L_IllegalFileNameError);
        return;
    }
```

And for `FORM.js`, find the following string:

```
else{if(IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName(c)!=-1)
```

Change it to:

```
else{var j=c.substring(c.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);if(IndexOfIllegalCharInUrlLeafName(j)!=-1)
```

Once completed, clear the browsers cache and re-test.

This solution worked for me.